# How to customize Google Chrome extension Desktop Notification balloon

Tags: notifications, desktop, google-chrome-extension

Can I remove title and "Settings" button near the close button of desktop notification balloon (Google Chrome extension Desktop Notification)?
Another question, can I customize its size, rounded corners etc. I know that I can use html and css to design the inner content writing it in notification.html file.
Also, I'm trying to open link (it is given in chrome extension api doc [Desktop Notifications](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html) > [Desktop notifications draft specification](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification)), but doesn't open, also html5rocks.com is invalid.
WHy why why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do any of those customizations you've mentioned.

To open a link add `target="_blank"` to it. If this doesn't work - add `onclick` event to a link and run `chrome.tabs.create({url:"http://example.com/"});`